# SQL "Update" Query occurring happens once in PHP "Foreach" loop but loop still runs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to have a foreach loop run through an array and update my database for each entry.

My code looks like this:

```
$basketID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
$basket = $_SESSION['basket'];
$x = array_count_values($basket);
foreach($x as $prodID => $Quant){
    $sql = "
    UPDATE products SET stock = (stock - '$Quant') 
    WHERE productID = '$prodID'; 

    INSERT INTO basketitems(basketID, productID, quantity)
    VALUES ('$basketID','$prodID','$Quant'); ";

    mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

The result at the moment is that the loop occurs say 5 times (if I have 5 items in the array) but the query only happens once [I placed a counter in to find out if it was breaking the loop and it counted 5 times]. If I remove the "Update" query then 5 items are inserted into the basketitems table.

Comment: Don't chain DB calls like that. you're simply assuming nothing could ever fail. Run multiple SINGLE queries (one update, one insert), and check for errors at each stage.

Comment: [this should error out](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Why doing multiple querys ? You can't write a proper SQL query that do the all update ?

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: It would be quite useful to see what is actually in `$_SESSION['basket']` as something here looks `hinky` but I am not sure what. Apart from the fact you should probably be using a transactions, assuming INNODB

Comment: Also it seems a little premature reducing stock while adding items to the users basket, afterall the purchase has not actually been confirmed at this point. I woudl guess at least 50% of baskets get forgotten about well before a purchase is actually made.

Comment: This work is just a small project and is the first time I have written anything like this. The specification is that the customer can save a basket and this is when the code runs to people leaving their basket won't matter. I need the query to save the basket into the database but also reduce the stock in the product table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the $_SESSION['basket'] contains an array with multiple product IDs in as I couldn't think of a way to store them across pages as I have small to  no knowledge on Javascript. It looks like this [1]=> 1 [2]=> 1 [3]=> 42 [4]=> 13 [5]=> 21 [6]=> 21 [7]=> 21 [8]=> 40. The code then counts how many times each value occurs so I have my quantity.

Comment: Session is a good place to store such data. If this app is ever to be used for real though you need to think about where and when you alter stock values a lot more carefully.